# Javascript if statement double exclamation mark operator redundancy

Tags: javascript

If I have an if statement that doesn't have a conditional operator, does it matter if I use the double exclamation mark operator - `!!`?

For example...

```
if ([]) {

}
```

vs...

```
if (!!([])) {

}
```

From what I understand - the operator is basically asking - "is this value truthy?". So it is redundant in this case. Is it redundant in all cases similar to this?

EDIT:

```
if (x) { console.log("hi"); }
if (!!x) { console.log("hi"); }
```

Will both of these print for any `x`? That is my question.

Comment: It is redundant in this case.

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Both of these will print for any `Boolean(x) === true`

For more detail, you can find [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) in JavaScript

For esier to understand, you can use `Boolean([]) // true`